# How to force all user's browsers to refresh for software update

Tags: refresh, page-refresh

I have a number of web applications that run for a number of businesses, day in and day out.

The applications are in PHP/MySQL/JS Running on a remote apache server.

For many years, I have performed updates at late night when the software is not in use.

I would like to be able to perform updates to the software during working hours, if possible.

I have many times asked my clients to make sure they shut the software down at night, and close their browsers - but can never guarantee that they have done so.

I have a refresh timer in the JS that trigger a browser to refresh at 11:59. It will happen If the browser is still open.

But I would like able to perform this refresh at any open browser - when I want.

I have mulled over a few ways to do this - including `cron` and database values that can be read and reset - but:

I wonder if anyone has had success with achieving this?

Comment: Have you tried making an ajax call on the client side and a php script on the server side checking the database in an endless loop? The js could force a refresh in the browser when it gets a response from this request. Search for long polling.

Answer (score 3):

You want to refresh all open browser tabs that are pointing at your xAMP-ish applications. A few questions:

1. Does the refresh need to be immediate, or can it be deferred? that is, do everyone's tabs need to be refreshed at the same time, regardless of user interaction; or is it acceptable to wait until the next request from each client, whenever it may be?
2. Can you schedule the refresh ahead of time (say, with at least 1 session-timeout interval lead-up time), or do you need a method that triggers refreshes immediately?

If you require immediate refreshes, with no ahead-of-time scheduling, you are out of luck. The only way to do this is to keep an open channel for asynchronous updates from the server to the clients, which is hard to do with plain Apache/PHP (see [comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)), [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)).

If you can make do with deferred refreshes (waiting until a user submits a request), you have several alternatives. For example, you can

- expire all sessions (by calling a script that removes all the corresponding server-side session files; found in `/var/lib/php/sessions/` in linux). Note that your users will not appreciate losing, say, their shopping-cart contents.
- use JavaScript to check a client-side `version` value (loaded at login-time, and kept in `localStorage` or similar) against incoming replies from the server (which would load it from a configuration file or a DB request). If the server-side value has changed, save whatever can be saved to localStorage (to avoid the previous scenario), inform the user, and refresh the page.

Alternatively, if you can schedule the refreshes with enough fore-warning, you can include instructions in server-replies that will invoke the refresh mechanism when needed. For example, such replies could change your current "reset at 11:59:59" code to read "reset at $requested_reset_time".

Comment: The client side just needs a single reply to trigger an update. This can be accomplished with long polling and that's actually quite simple.

Comment: @EnricoDias long-polling is one of the mechanisms used for comet (see above). It is not free: it keeps a connection open, and for xAMP, this means idling one of apache's worker threads indefinitely. Applications that could support hundreds or thousands of users would be limited to the dozen or so apache workers. With other server stacks, sure. With xAMP, long-polling may be simple, but it is suicidal.

Comment: You can use 1 worker to all clients by listening connections directly on php using sockets. You need an open connection for each client and nothing else. There are no cpu or memory consumed.

Comment: @EnricoDias can you post a link to working code that implements that? It seems possible, and I am always ready to learn. However, manual socket management is certainly not standard PHP practice.

Comment: I've done this manually a few years ago and it wasn't hard, but nowadays you can find entire frameworks dedicated to help you with that, such as Workerman: https://github.com/walkor/Workerman

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem, you would want control over when the user sees 'fresh' content and when the cached stuff is okay. If this is right, 
Add the following in your head content -

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Upon receiving this header, user's browser will automatically fetch a fresh content. And you can flip on/off the above lines to suit your needs.  This might not be the most sophisticated way of achieving the desired functionality but worth trying.

Comment: The problem here is if they left the page open and continue using it (for example, a javascript based webapp with no page "refresh" when different pages are clicked), it won't fetch anything new, OP wants a way to tell the browser automatically on command when he's deployed a new update and refresh the browser if so

Comment: I totally agree. If they keep same page open then that's a problem. But if they navigate to any other page in the same app then it shouldn'e be a problem.
Stnfordly : I just got a better idea. You can use notification (precisely, data notification). Client app will act on the data notification and will refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things to consider before doing something like this. For example, if someone is actively working on a page, maybe filling out a form or something and you were able to refresh their window, that could create a negative user experience. I believe some of the other answers here addressed some other concerns as well.

That said, I know from working with the Launch Darkly feature flag service that it can be done. I don't understand all the inner workings, unfortunately, but my understanding is that the service uses observables to watch for updates. Observables are similar to promises, except they continuously watch for new changes to their target. You could then force a page reload (or perhaps an alert to the user, prompting one) when the target updates.